# Having trouble in executing prepared statement query in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a table with table schema and a prepared statement.

```
CREATE TABLE studentexam
    (`ID` int, `Student` varchar(4), `Exam` varchar(2))
;

INSERT INTO studentexam
    (`ID`, `Student`, `Exam`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Kavi', 'BE'),
    (2, 'MGR', 'BA'),
    (3, 'MGR1', 'BE')
;

SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'max(case when exam = ''',
      exam,
      ''' then student end) AS `',
      exam, '`'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
from studentexam;

SET @sql 
    = CONCAT('SELECT ', @sql, ' 
              from studentexam
              group by id;');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c5210/2)

The problem is,when i run this query in sqlfiddle,it works great,but when i run this similar query with similar table schema in phpmyadmin,it doesn work.
I don't get any sort of errors but a simple message like "Query has been executed successfully".
I don't see any results or any errors.please help.

Comment: phpmyadmin by default shows results of last statement, and there is no output to show for last statement.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me in phpMyAdmin 4.0.6; I see the three rows of results. I am using PHP 5.5.3 and MySQL 5.5.31 with the mysqli extension.

However I tried a second time and got:

> #1243 - Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to EXECUTE.